# getting the selected list item of an unordered list in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use the selected item from this list to display the products of that type in the same page by changing the sql query in php.
I think I will need to use the post array but I can't match the correct way.

```
<ul id="1">
    <li><a href="shop.php">clothes</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.php">shoes</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.php">bags</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.php">sunglasses</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.php">accessories</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @A.alhamdani In the future, please include your code in your questions in text form rather than linking to images of it.

Comment: i think you need a `<select>`box a form input element [check](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Add a query string to each link in your list that matches the item you want to find, like this:

```
<li><a href="shop.php?item=clothes">clothes</a></li>
```

Then in shop.php, you can find which link was clicked in `$_GET['item']`.

---

If you wanted to use `$_POST`, you would need to change your list of links to a `<select>` element in an HTML form. However, using `GET` rather than `POST` is typically more appropriate for things like this where you are only selecting different options rather than changing data on your server. One advantage to using `GET` is that having the item in the URL provides a link to that specific query that your users can bookmark.

Comment: and what if the results are fetched from a database could i replace the value assigned to "item" with a query to select the filed fetched from or there is another way ?

Comment: Yes, I assume the item is a product category. If that is the case, you should be able to use the value of `$_GET['item']` in the WHERE clause of your product query.